# Combine multiple factor columns into a single numeric column

Tags: r, dplyr

Can someone think of a more interesting way to combine multiple factor columns into a single numeric column?

MWE dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(q.82=factor(c(1,2,2,1,1)), q.77=factor(c(2,1,1,1,1)), q.72=factor(c(1,1,1,2,2)))
levels(df$q.82) <- c("","$80 and above")
levels(df$q.77) <- c("", "$75 to $79")
levels(df$q.72) <- c("", "$70 to $74")

str(df$q.82)

Factor w/ 2 levels "","$80 and above": 1 2 2 1 1
```

`df` looks like this:

```
           q.82       q.77       q.72
1               $74 to $79           
2 $80 and above                      
3 $80 and above                      
4                          $70 to $74
5                          $70 to $74
```

What I'd like is something like this, where the columns are numeric:

```
  q.82 q.77 q.72  q
1    0   77    0 77
2   82    0    0 82
3   82    0    0 82
4    0    0   72 72
5    0    0   72 72
```

The following works, but seems klunky—mostly because the actual dataset has many columns.

```
df$q.82  <- as.numeric(as.factor(df$q.82))
df$q.82[df$q.82 == 2] <- 82
df$q.82[df$q.82 == 1] <- 0
df$q.77  <- as.numeric(as.factor(df$q.77))
df$q.77[df$q.77 == 2] <- 77
df$q.77[df$q.77 == 1] <- 0
df$q.72  <- as.numeric(as.factor(df$q.72))
df$q.72[df$q.72 == 2] <- 72
df$q.72[df$q.72 == 1] <- 0

df <- df %>% mutate(q=q.82+q.77+q.72)
```

Comment: Transforming "$80 and above" to 82 seems like a serious mistake that could invalidate all subsequent statistical analyses.

Comment: why don't you just write `82` instead of `$80 and above` and `0` isntead of `''` in the factor level bit. (changing values as necessary) then adding them in 1 line: `df$q <- as.numeric(as.character(df$q.82))+as.numeric(as.character(df$q.77))+as.numeric(as.character(df$q.72))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another base R method, where we replace non-blank value in the column with the numeric part in the column name using `sub`.

```
df[] <- t(as.integer(sub(".*?(\\d+)", "\\1", names(df))) * t(df != ""))
df
#  q.82 q.77 q.72
#1    0   77    0
#2   82    0    0
#3   82    0    0
#4    0    0   72
#5    0    0   72
```

and then if you want to row-wise sum the values you can use `rowSums`

```
df$q <- rowSums(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible approach with base R using `sapply`:

1. For each column, replace non-empty strings by the numeric part of the column name and replace empty strings by zero.
2. Add an additional column `q` that contains the summed value of each row.

```r
out_df <- sapply(names(df), function(name) {
      ifelse(nchar(as.character(df[[name]])) > 0, as.numeric(sub("^q\\.", "", name)), 0)
    })     
out_df <- transform(out_df, q = rowSums(out_df))

out_df
#>   q.82 q.77 q.72  q
#> 1    0   77    0 77
#> 2   82    0    0 82
#> 3   82    0    0 82
#> 4    0    0   72 72
#> 5    0    0   72 72
```

Similarly, using the `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_out <- imap_dfc(.x = df, .f =  ~{
          if_else(nchar(as.character(.x)) > 0, as.numeric(str_remove(.y, "^q\\.")), 0)          
        }) %>%
    mutate(q = rowSums(.))

df_out
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>    q.82  q.77  q.72     q
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0    77     0    77
#> 2    82     0     0    82
#> 3    82     0     0    82
#> 4     0     0    72    72
#> 5     0     0    72    72
```

Or with `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

for(j in names(df))
  set(df, j = j, value = ifelse(nchar(as.character(df[[j]])) > 0, as.numeric(sub("^q\\.", "", j)), 0))

df[, q := rowSums(.SD)][]
#>    q.82 q.77 q.72  q
#> 1:    0   77    0 77
#> 2:   82    0    0 82
#> 3:   82    0    0 82
#> 4:    0    0   72 72
#> 5:    0    0   72 72
```

**Data**

```r
df <- data.frame(q.82=factor(c(1,2,2,1,1)), q.77=factor(c(2,1,1,1,1)), q.72=factor(c(1,1,1,2,2)))
levels(df$q.82) <- c("","$80 and above")
levels(df$q.77) <- c("", "$75 to $79")
levels(df$q.72) <- c("", "$70 to $74")
```